# regex how to remove commas after a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, expression

I am currently trying to remove any commas after the specific word 'SUM(' and Before the last ')' by using a regex. In other words, I want to remove all the beginning and end commas inside of the function SUM(). I am using the javascript function replace to do this on a regex.

Here are examples to illustrate what I am trying to do after the replace function is called with a regex:

```
SUM(,,,,1,2,)  // result should be SUM(1,2)
SUM(,1,2,)    // result should be SUM(1,2)
SUM(,1,2,,,)  // result should be SUM(1,2)
SUM(,,,,1,34) // result should be SUM(1,34)
SUM(,,,,0,0,0) // result should be SUM(0,0,0)
```

Currently I have been trying this regex:

```
(^SUM\()\,|(\,+)\)$
```

But I only want to match on the commas that are after the word 'SUM(' and Before the last bracket ')'. Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
/(^SUM)\(,*(.*?),*\)/gm
```

And replace it with `$1($2)`.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ5lT0/6)

Comment: If he only wants to match lines that start with 'SUM' shouldn't it be `/SUM\(,+(.*?),+\)/` instead?

Comment: @JordanRobinson If he wants *what you said*, yes, you are right ..! I didn't write `SUM` in the pattern because OP didn't mention it.

Comment: Doesn't work for `SUM(,1,2)`, it's outside of OP scope, but anyway - ideas would be nice?

Answer (score 0):

Replace multiple commas with one comma, then fix up the beginning and end:

```
str . 
  replace(/,+/g, ',') . 
  replace(/\(,/, '(') . 
  replace(/,\)/, ')')
```

If you don't care about removing multiple commas between items, then

```
str . replace(/\(,+/g, '(') . replace(/,+\(/, '(')
```

You could use combine these into a single regexp as

```js
var str = "SUM(,1,2,,,)";
var result = str.replace(/(\(),+|,+(\))|(,),*/g, '$1$2$3')
//                        ^^^^^^               MATCH (,,,
//                               ^^^^^^        MATCH ,,,)
//                                      ^^^    MATCH commas between items
                             

document.write(result);
```